# Creating email from C# program and sending it to Gmail by POST

Tags: c#, email, gmail

I am creating an email like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    string.Format("mailto:{0}?&subject=Test&body={1}", 
        string.Join(", ", emails), 
        string.Join("\n", temp.ToArray())
    )
);
```

However Gmail says that the link is too long. I've read [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/faq#url_length) and it seems that it would solve my issue if I sent this via POST since 16K would be enough for me. Is it possible to do that and how?

**UPDATE** I mentioned Gmail's case in the example, but I need any default email software to work with this. For example if it opened with Outlook, I would need it work too.

**QUESTION UPDATE/CLARIFICATION** How do I send the request (above) using POST instead of using GET (because GET's limit is too short)?

Comment: Try `WebClient` and its method.

Comment: After I updated my question, I think WebClient no longer suits my needs since I have to specify the exact url. Am I right?

Comment: If 16K is not enough, maybe you could use an attachment instead of a body ?

Comment: No, 16K would be more than enough for me. I just do not know how to send this in POST.

Comment: The link you provided is for Google Chart, it has nothing to do with mailto links. GET and POST are HTTP verbs, you don't have any control on how the Google Notifier translates mailto protocols to HTTP requests.

Comment: I got this link provided in a similar, yet different question. I assumed that the limit is the same for all services provided by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two choices.

One is to create your message body as an attachment, by adding `&attachment=<filename.html>` to your `mailto` URL. Some email clients support this, perhaps the Google code that translates `mailto` links into GMail requests does, too.

If the above doesn't work, and you're sure you only want to use GMail, you'll need to switch to communication with the server directly. You can use the GMail SMTP server. Read here about their support for authentication: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview.

Comment: The problem is that I want this to be available to all posibilites. To gmail, to outlook, to...

Comment: We actually decided to allow sending instantly instead of allowing to modify something in midway thus we used smtp client. Anyways, attachment seems like a decent idea thus I mark this as a solution. Thank you :)